# Posgresql/SQL aggregate/sum lots of data/tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database as follows:

- I have a customer table each with its own ID
- I have a large table which stores data as follows: customerid, hour, amount (bigint).

Every hour each customer inserts a row into this large table (with 10k customers I get 240000 data points per day)

I have created one materialized view for each customer from the large table to speed up reading (these views only have hour, amount).

The problem I have now is: how can I aggregate all of these tables to get the total? I want to create another materialized view which stores the total consumption for that hour for all customers, it has to sum thousands of columns from different tables together.

I have tried using joins between thousands of these amount columns and summing each column but the statements are way too long and it breaks.

How can I aggregate so much data?

Thanks.

Comment: Start with EXPLAIN(ANALYZE, VERBOSE, BUFFERS) to see what query plan is created and where the performance issues are located. Maybe you need some indexes or rewrite your unknown query.

Comment: use the parent table or create  a materialized view for all custmers

Comment: You need to build a datawarehouse. You can populate it with batch (small or big) or even, in some case, update it with triggers.

Comment: The trick is to NOT aggregate every time - but update the aggregated values every time the original data is updated. Of course this does not mean in the same transaction - you can simply post a message to a queue which will be picked up by a background worker.